# sudo lshw -C network not showing any results

Tags: wireless, networking

When I type the command `sudo lshw -C network`, it returns

```
> PCI (sys)
```

and exits.

I have problems with wireless network. The network icon doesn't show any wireless connection, just the section *Wireless Networks*. It just show Ethernet. I can't connect to any network because i have a WiFi modem and no cable. I'm a new user to Ubuntu.

My wireless adapter is Broadcom BCM4312 and using I'm using Dell Inspiron Mini 1011 running Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Broadcom wireless devices use proprietary drivers that don't get enabled by default. See if this website sheds some light on your issue.

http://www.ubuntulinuxguide.com/proprietarydrivers.htm

Answer (score 0):

Please check the terminal command:

```
lspci -nn | grep 0280
```

Is your device 14e4:4315? If so, it requires firmware. With a temporary wired ethernet connection, do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Detach the ethernet and reboot.

If your device is not 14e4:4315, please post the result and we'll proceed.